# Error when running mvn archetype:generate Google App Engine archetypes

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, command-line

I am an iOS developer, not a Java developer. My goal is to build a simple backend for my iPhone app. I am trying to get up and running with Google App Engine Endpoints, following these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world

I have confirmed that I have installed Maven. The command mvn -verion produces:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T07:57:37-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I then try to perform the second step in the linked instructions, this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.26 -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:
```

And I always get this response:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[INFO] Your filter doesn't match any archetype, so try again with another value.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.207 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-26T18:42:19-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Again, I am not a Java developer but it seems that my Maven setup cannot find the archetype catalog. I have double and triple checked that my filter is correct.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Very probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32800381/1743880

Comment: Checking the link Tunaki linked in his answer the catalog has been filled. Are you still having issues? If so you should create a Bug report[1]. Keep in mind it might be a maven issue which is outside of Google's control.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry

Comment: Thank you @Ryan. This issue is no longer occurring, it appears Tunaki was correct.

Comment: @Tunaki, please feel free to answer this question and I will confirm your answer.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to close this question as duplicate of the other one, since it also answers it. I just voted for that so you could accept the duplicate.